# android webView acces temp files

Tags: android, html, webview

I'd like to know if there is a way to download files that webView is loading from external link when is loading an internal html source. 
For example I have a simple html string that loads an image from an external link:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Some text</h2>
<img src="http://s22.postimg.org/473fk850x/dejit.jpg"
</body>
</html>
```

I can see what is loading using a listener:

```
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("log", "url is: " + url);
        }
    });
```

But how can I get(download it as a file) the image from webView, I suppose that there is a kind of temp where image goes first and then they're loaded in webView. I don't want to take link from here and download it again, it's double trafic...

Note that i need to do that with **all loaded resources** like img or css, for making my own cache implementation that will work in offline mode too - if no internet connection I'l replace external link with internal one...

Answer (score 0):

You can override all resource loading for webView

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (/*has internet*/) {
                    WebResourceResponse resultFromInternet = super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
                    // store result to internet
                    return resultFromInternet;
                } else {
                    // return resource from local cache
                    return new WebResourceResponse(...);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: the point is that i'd like to store result - only img, css or js (not all source) in my files but to not duplicate traffic, loading them in webview and downloading them separately. I want to take them somehow from webView. But your `resultFromInternet` is all source including html

Comment: you can get mimetype from resource downloaded and save to local cache only "text/css", "image/*", "text/javascript" etc.

Comment: well, this method like it's mentioned in android [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html#WebResourceResponse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream)) was aded in API 21 and in my gradle file is indicated minSdkVersion 17 - targetSdkVersion 22  and this method is not running at all...

Comment: For old sdk version you can use deprecated http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)